# Low beam head lights quit working

Tags: honda, electrical, headlight, crv

My low beam headlights quit working. I checked all of the fuses. They are good.  What are my next steps?

Comment: Did you check the bulbs themselves to make sure they're good?

Comment: Bulbs, wiring/contact, relays

Comment: No haven't yet, but I'll try to check them.  Would they burn out at the same time?  Tks for you input!

Comment: Had the bulbs checked and the were good, I'm going to try the relay next.

Answer (score 1):

If both low beams stop working at the same time, there are a few things to check:

- Are the bulbs still good, it's not unheard of for both to fail at the same time, or close to each other.
- Are the fuses and relays working correctly.
- Is the switch working correctly - quite a few cars are known for having weak headlight switches that either wear out or burn out the contacts over time, although this is more prevalent in older cars with un-relayed headlamps.
- Is the wiring all good - are there any loose connections, damaged wires or badly corroded earth points.